# The reference title does not appear in the bibliography page texmaker

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have problem when defining the references for my report. The name of the reference didn't appear for the first 6 reference .
here is the code:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{Germanyenergiewende,
  title = {{Germany's Energiewende – The Easy Guide}},
  url = {https://www.cleanenergywire.org/easyguide#:~:text=Timeline-,What%20is%20the%20Energiewende%3F,energies%20in%20the%20power%20sector},
  urldate = {2020-10-13},

}

@INPROCEEDINGS{Germanygreenhouse,
  title = {Germany’s greenhouse gas emissions and energy transition targets},
  url = {https://www.cleanenergywire.org/factsheets/germanys-greenhouse-gas-emissions-and-climate-targets},
  urldate = {2020-10-13},

}
%ElectricVehicles
@INPROCEEDINGS{3,   
  title = {Electric Vehicles Charging Infrastructure},
  url = {https://www.gtai.de/gtai-en/invest/industries/energy/electric-vehicles-charging-infrastructure-65212},
  urldate = {2020-10-13},

}
%ChargingInfrastructure
@BOOK{4,
  title = {Charging Infrastructure for Electric Vehicles in Germany},
  author ={German National Platform for Electric Mobility (NPE) Berlin},
  volume={33},
  year={2015},
  url = {http://nationale-plattform-elektromobilitaet.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Redaktion/AG3_Statusbericht_LIS_2015_engl_klein_bf.pdf},
  urldate = {2020-10-10},

}
% A dynamic charging strategy with hybrid fast charging station for electric vehicles
@INPROCEEDINGS{5,
  title = {A dynamic charging strategy with hybrid fast charging station for electric vehicles},
  url = {https://www.x-mol.com/paper/1254455835037163520?recommendPaper=1281088749953531904},
  urldate = {2020-10-14},

}
```

What I get when simulating the code is :
[image: Result of the bibliography code]

Comment: Please, provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: Obviously this shouldn't be happening. Unfortunately, it is almost impossible to investigate this issue any further as the question stands now. All I can say at the moment is that the `.bib` entries shown in the question have no issues that would stop them from compiling properly (the content of some entries is a bit questionable, for example if entry `5` has neither an `author`, nor a `title`, `booktitle` or `editor` it probably shouldn't be an `@INPROCEEDINGS`, but that should not cause what you are seeing). ...

Comment: ... Please show us a compilable example document (complete with `\documentclass`, **relevant bits** of your preamble and just as much of the document body between `\begin{document}...\end{document}` so we can reproduce your issue) that reproduces your problem with as little code as possible, a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864. Without such an MWE it will be very hard to help you properly, I'm afraid.

Comment: Any news here? As the question stands now we cannot really offer you any useful advice. We need to see a compilable example document that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please compile this code. Use `biblatex` and  `biber`. It should be compiled 4-5 times until LaTeX  suits everything and there are no more warnings of undefined references.

If your configuration doesn't do it automatically, do it manually.

References look good (`biber` ends normally with no complaints). There are only five references in your file, not six.

[image: out]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}   
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
natbib=true,
style=ieee,
]{biblatex} 

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname49.bib}        
@INPROCEEDINGS{Germanyenergiewende,
    title = {{Germany's Energiewende – The Easy Guide}},
    url = {https://www.cleanenergywire.org/easyguide#:~:text=Timeline-,What%20is%20the%20Energiewende%3F,energies%20in%20the%20power%20sector},
        urldate = {2020-10-13},         
    }
    
    @INPROCEEDINGS{Germanygreenhouse,
        title = {Germany’s greenhouse gas emissions and energy transition targets},
        url = {https://www.cleanenergywire.org/factsheets/germanys-greenhouse-gas-emissions-and-climate-targets},
        urldate = {2020-10-13},         
    }
    %ElectricVehicles
    @INPROCEEDINGS{3,   
        title = {Electric Vehicles Charging Infrastructure},
        url = {https://www.gtai.de/gtai-en/invest/industries/energy/electric-vehicles-charging-infrastructure-65212},
        urldate = {2020-10-13},         
    }
    %ChargingInfrastructure
    @BOOK{4,
        title = {Charging Infrastructure for Electric Vehicles in Germany},
        author ={German National Platform for Electric Mobility (NPE) Berlin},
        volume={33},
        year={2015},
        url = {http://nationale-plattform-elektromobilitaet.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Redaktion/AG3_Statusbericht_LIS_2015_engl_klein_bf.pdf},
        urldate = {2020-10-10},         
    }
    % A dynamic charging strategy with hybrid fast charging station for electric vehicles
    @INPROCEEDINGS{5,
        title = {A dynamic charging strategy with hybrid fast charging station for electric vehicles},
        url = {https://www.x-mol.com/paper/1254455835037163520?recommendPaper=1281088749953531904},
        urldate = {2020-10-14},         
    }

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname49.bib}

\begin{document}
    
See \citep{Germanyenergiewende}  and \citep{Germanygreenhouse} and  \citep{3}  and \citep{4}    and     \citep{5} 
    
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```